# height of text compare to an image

Tags: html, css

I can't put the text in the middle height of the image it is in with.
This is what I write in the HTML:

```
<p><img class="languagesIcons" src="img/x.png">x</p>
```

This is what I write in the CSS:

```
.languagesIcons {
   width: 55px;
   margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}
```

All of that runs in a `<div>` which its CSS is:

```
#languages {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   font-size: 22px;
   gap: 30px;
   padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Written in the first line..., I want to put the text middle height of the photo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position:absolute`on the image and the text placed in a span for example and use `position:relative`on the container which is a p tag here. Then you can adjust its position with `transform:translateY()`for example.
**See the code below :**

```css
p{
position:relative
}

.languagesIcons {
   width: 55px;
   margin: 0 10px 0 0;
   position:absolute
}
div{
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
   font-size: 22px;
   gap: 30px;
   padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}
span{
position:absolute;
transform:translateY(50%)
}
```

```html
<div><p><img class="languagesIcons" src="img/x.png"><span>x</span></p></div>
```

Comment: To be honest, only needed the span + css you did, thank you so much ♥

Answer (score 1):

You could just add vertical-align:middle to your languageIcons class:

```
.languageIcons{
width:55px;
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To vertically align text and image, use :

```
<p>
    <img class="languagesIcons" src="img/x.png" style="vertical-align: middle;" >
    <span style="vertical-align: middle;" >x</span>
</p>
```